# Reusing Struts2 core validations in a custom validator

Tags: validation, struts2, customvalidator

We are developing a new struts2 custom validator.

This validator checks, if user account number has a valid format.
For this validator, the account number must not be `null` and integer.

There are two approaches:

1. We develop the validator and assume that user use
   `@IntRangeFieldValidator` and `@RequiredFieldValidator` before using
   our validator

   ```
   @IntRangeFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.FIELD, min = "1", key = "validate.int.min")
   @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, key = "validate.required")    
   @CustomValidator(type = "accountNumber", message = "Price must be a number")
   public void setAccount(Integer accountNumber){}
   ```

   In this way, the validation will be like as shown below

   ```
   public class AccountNamuberValidator extends FieldValidatorSupport {

       String fieldName = getFieldName();
       String val = (String) getFieldValue(fieldName, object);

       if (val == null && (value instanceof String ) &&... ) {
           //we are assumption is not correct we just return
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

   As you can see we do not deal ourselves with any validations that we assume to be done by integer validation or required validation. If any thing goes wrong we return and do not add any filed error.
2. Next approach is that we develop a sophisticated account number
   validation which call integer validation and required validation
   before starting his own validation check. Here we can, some how,
   chain validation to each other.

   ```
   public class AccountNamuberValidator extends FieldValidatorSupport {

       String fieldName = getFieldName();
       String val = (String) getFieldValue(fieldName, object);
       //Call struts required validaitor
       //Call struts integer validaitor
       //Go on with account number validation
   }
   ```

   So using this validator will be as:

   ```
   @CustomValidator(type = "accountNumber", message = "Price must be a number")
   public void setAccount(Integer accountNumber){}
   ```

---

Now here are the questions:

- Is it possible to do second approch (I could not find how can I call Struts2 validators from my custom validator)?
- Which approach is better? (As I found that Strut uses first approach)

Comment: Any reason to use second approach?

Comment: Well, in second one, developers will not require to call integer and required validaitons before this validation, and their code will be smaller.

Comment: If struts used the second approach the number of validators would be equal to the number of combinations of simple validators.

Comment: I'm not sure this is that useful, particularly in this case. Yes, you could re-use the core logic of the validators, but if you're just checking for null/empty and all digits, it's a single regex already.